# Coordinates in UTM 19Q, WGS84

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, point, utm

I am unable to map the following coordinates:

UTM 19Q, WGS84: 430293.76 N and 2128432.03 E.

I cannot find the WKID for UTM 19Q, WGS84. The point should be somewhere in the Dominican Republic. For this area in the past I have used WKID 32619. Does anyone know the WKID for UTM 19Q, WGS84? I have tried converting the coordinates to decimal degrees as well.

Comment: 19Q is not a UTM zone, it's an MGRS search grid, in UTM zone 19N.

Comment: I have tried using UTM zone 19 to plot and it doesn't work- It ends up in South America. Do you know which WKID I should be using? When converting to lat/long I got 3.768315  -54.49141.

Answer (score 2):

They sent me the wrong coordinates. I switched the northings/eastings and was able to map them.